# JS does not get value of [element].style.animationPlayState

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to change the value of sun.style.animationPlayState for the "sun" html element when a button is clicked.

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
  let btn = document.getElementById("button");
  let sun = document.getElementById("sun");
  let sky = document.getElementById("animation-stage");
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //let playState = window.getComputedStyle(sun).animationPlayState;
    //console.log(playState);
    if (sun.style.animationPlayState === "paused"){
      sun.style.animationPlayState = "running";
      sky.style.animationPlayState = "running";
    } else {
      sun.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
      sky.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    }
  } )
}
```

I noticed that the first time this function is called, sun.style.animationPlayState is set to empty string, when it should be set to 'running'. Why is this the case?

I tried to check if sun.style.animationPlayState was "running" but it was set to empty string in JS.

Comment: You have to call `getComputedStyle` in order to get the state, or it just returns the value of the property in the inline `style` attribute.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help!